# Use keyfile for encrypted swap

Tags: 11.10, security, encryption, swap, encrypted-partition

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 using the alternate CD and set up an ecrypted root and swap partition. Now, during boot, I have to enter a password for the root and a passwort for the swap partitition. I want to get rid of the password for the swap partition and replace it by a keyfile that's stored on the root partition. How can this be done? Is there maybe some hidden option in Ubuntu so I don't have to configure this in some configuration files? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you add the contents of your `/etc/crypttab`? If it contains sensitive informations make sure, they are blanked out.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think it needs to be this way by design - 2 passwords.

After the initial boot up where you enter 2 passwords
from then on you can use hibernate mode securely.

When you resume from hibernation it's just the one password.

Answer (score -1):

You have to reinstall. I forget the terms, but you want one encrypted physical partition and then you just put LVM (maybe?) partitions on top of this one.